# Why is it always wrong to spell out the n-word?

Tags: language, politics

Many news outlets never ever spell out the n-word, even when discussing the word or quoting someone.
I'm wondering what's the reasoning for doing so.

To clarify: I fully understand why it is wrong to use the word to describe or refer to a person.
What I don't understand is how anyone can be offended by usage like, "<some person> amply deserved getting sacked for calling their superior <n-word, spelled out>."

Clearly, the person doing the name-calling did something wrong:
In addition to insulting their boss, they implicitly asserted the existence of a race and attached to it a wide, culturally understood set of negative stereotypes about that race, thereby strengthening the shared belief in the existence of that race and the truth of those stereotypes, all by using one word.

But what is the damage done by describing explicitly what happened?

Comment: It's self protection, it can be taken out of context and people will crucify you for  it.

Comment: It's a *taboo*. https://simplyphilosophy.org/study/what-taboo/

Comment: "But what is the damage done by describing explicitly what happened?" This is a religious phenomena. Just as religion has certain practices that may seem arbitrary and pointless to outsiders, this is something like that. The damage is that the religious tenet was violated.

Comment: @AmeetSharma: It is literally that, in the Durkheim-ian sense of religion, rather than the edgy atheist sense of implying it means it's something to sneer at. A recurring issue, has seen the development of a social value, in thus case a taboo, which binds people together in enacting & defending it. Free speech, and habeus corpus, are literally sacred values, in this context (to some communities). Like those who write G-d, or refuse to depict Mohammed.

Comment: It’s unfortunate, but I don’t think you’ll get good feedback to a question like this here. People will up-vote or down-vote based on their personal moral sentiment and political ideology, not on the presence or lack of reasoned argumentation. There is a lot of moralizing in the comments and answers.

Comment: It is like saying "don't think of elephants". To avoid the concept from raising in a discussion, start by not using it.

Comment: A bit more lighthearted: since there are actually two n-words that are becoming more and more unsayable, I propose we distinguish them as the ones favoured by Drs. King and Dre, respectively.

Comment: Here's a conversation about this exact topic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ya6oHUkG4tw

Answer (score 4):

Philosophers of language sometimes call this phenomenon the *embedding failure* of slurs (see, e.g., Bolinger, 2017). I suggest you read up on that, if the topic interests you. Just search for `embedding failure slurs` on Google Scholar or whatever, there's a huge literature on the topic.

Most philosophers of language don't find the question whether slurs *ought* to be embeddable interesting. That is to say, perhaps "Schiphol is a <slur>" should be pragmatically very different from "Schiphol is not a <slur>", but it just turns out that these two sentences have interesting features in common, having to do with the slur, regardless of whether it is or is not negated. Rather, philosophers take embedding failures as linguistic data, and try to account for them with their theories of the semantics and pragmatics of slurs.

Bolinger, R. J. (2017). The Pragmatics of Slurs. *Noûs*, 51(3), 439–462. https://doi.org/10.1111/nous.12090

Comment: And when these philosophers refer to these words, do they spell them out? Because that’s going to reveal what they really think.

Comment: The n-word is spelled out in Bollinger (2017), along with others, @JustSomeOldMan

Comment: Thanks, that's very interesting.  Would you say the usage I cited above "<A> called <B> a <C>" is a very short direct quotation (although without quotation marks) and therefore insulated as per Bolinger?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it does seem to fall under that category. Bear in mind, though, that what Bolinger is doing is formulating a theory in pragmatics that aims at predicting (successfully or not) whether some uses of slurs *will* be deemed acceptable or not by speakers generally; not formulating a theory in ethics that aims at ruling which uses of slurs *should* be deemed acceptable.

Comment: Well, that's not part of his model, it's part of the data he's reviewing: he states that it **is** deemed acceptable to use a slur when it's insulated.  He goes so far as to say that that's uncontroversial.  Looking at the discussion here and elsewhere, I think he might be wrong.

Comment: Oh, I'm sure she (Renée Bolinger is a woman) is wrong about many things, as are all theorists always. I just offered her paper as a good example of the kind of work that might help with the worry in your question. Many other papers can be found [here](https://philpapers.org/browse/slurs/). Also, perhaps take a look at the SEP entry on [thick ethical concepts](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/thick-ethical-concepts/).

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a simple binary problem; there are levels to consider along the lines of this (overly simplistic) distinction:

- Words that are merely meant to be insulting, disparaging, bullying, degrading, etc.
- Words that are politically problematic: that carry the weight of social oppression, historical group violence, or deep-seated cultural hatred.

If we use terms of the first sort — like 'fatty', 'nerd', 'd_kwad', 'f_khead', 'sh_t-for-brains', etc, — we hurt people's feelings — sometimes extremely badly — but at the end of the day it is personal and individual, without any real social or political teeth to it. People get called names and they (usually, not always) survive and grow. It's a nasty moment in human life, sometimes even a fatal one, but it's a moment that *can* pass.

However, when we use terms of the second sort — as people in the US sometimes do for blacks, Jews, Muslims, women, gays, and others — we're not just hurting feelings. We are echoing the language that mobs of white men used during lynchings and slave auctions; that Nazis used while rounding up people for concentration camps; that men use during sexual assaults; that Right-wing pundits use to stir up anti-Islamic hatred. It is not the language of a person degrading another person; it is the language of a society degrading a group, and that group degradation continues as long as the language is kept alive.

Respectable news outlets and other forms of mass media do not spell out or use the n-word (or similar terms), not because they're worried they might offend some particular person, but because the use of the word carries the weight of social oppression. If news outlets regularly used that word, we would be right back in the mindset of the segregationist South, where whites are 'whites' and blacks are 'n_s', and any possibility of equality or fair treatment fades away like the morning dew. Instead, respectable news outlets prefer to talk about 'people', without unnecessary reference to stigmatizing language.

Comment: Yet plenty of other slurs don't face the same level of ostracism. That sounds like a posteriori, ad hoc justification for a childlike, pseudo religious taboo. And does not change the fact that the word *does* exist and that some people use it. Why is it taboo to make a citation of those people to hold them up to their responsibility while never using the word itself to refer to actual people ?

Comment: This answer does not cover important realistic elements, such as forbidding even simply meta-references to “nigger” is often a power-play and a way to undermine important conversations rather than have them. This answer is a simplistic capitulation to claimed offense and uses copious loaded language to evoke emotions.

Comment: I’m not sure how accurate this answer is, but it certainly a plausible perspective.  Worthy of an upvote.

Comment: @armand: That's simply not true. I can lay out a list of words that are just as ostracized as n___: k___ for Jews, c___ for women, f___ for gays, etc. Group degradation/domination words are hardly uncommon. The main difference between these words is that there's a notable subsection of the US population that *really, really* wants to degrade and oppress blacks,  with monomaniacal focus. We only have the issue of the n-word because lots of d__kheads are out there wanting to use it in political speech.

Comment: @JustSomeOldMan: That strikes me as nonsensical. There is literally **no** conversation that **requires** the use of the n-word (except for discussions of the n-word itself, of course). It's as though you're suggesting we cannot have a conversation about women without using the b-word. Someone who cannot talk about women without using the b-word needs therapy; someone who cannot talk about blacks without using the n-word needs to get over themselves. Being blocked from talking like an a-hole doesn't make one the victim of a power-play. It actually makes one appear better than they are.

Comment: "except for discussions of the n-word itself, of course"  But that's exactly what the OP is talking about and what is prohibited by American society.  In such discussions one can never spell out the n-word. Look at the incidents described here: https://www.theatlantic.com/ideas/archive/2019/08/whites-refer-to-the-n-word/596872/ and here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J2r5oMy6Pes. Are these folks making up these incidents? This is a completely different phenomenon from the b-word or c-word.

Comment: Another thing that makes this different from those other words. The word is used continuously in hip-hop. Kids grow up listening to the word being used by the very people it is supposed to offend. We don't say it's ok for women to go around calling other women the b-word. Look at this incident: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9_-gn8Mm2xc This isn't just about being kind to your fellow human beings. This is something else. It has actually turned the n-word into some kind of joke. Rather than reducing racist thoughts and intentions, this is more like some kind of game/ritual.

Comment: @AmeetSharma: Again, the only difference here is that a notable subsection of the US population *really, really* wants to use the n-word as a form of social oppression. I've heard women call each other the b-word (affectionately); I've heard gay men call each other f__s without meaning any harm by it; sometimes a word of oppression becomes a word of mutual recognition. I do not doubt for a moment that professionals and academics might get fired for trying to discuss the c-word (or heaven forfend the k-word), but those words do not come up anywhere near as systematically in public discourse.

Comment: @TedWrigley, so prohibiting non-black fans from singing rap lyrics that include the n-word... that somehow helps in preventing this notable subsection from using the word as a form of oppression?

Comment: @AmeetSharma: We cannot judge a philosophy by ideologues who take it to extremes; that's straw-man argumentation. Either one is willing to grasp the basic principle or one isn't; but that's not something I concern myself with.

Comment: @TedWrigley, "that's straw-man argumentation"... but that's the topic of the OP. There are clearly innocent uses of the word rare as they might be. However, with the n-word, unlike with other words, we throw out all context and intent in these innocent cases.

Comment: As @AmeetSharma pointed out: I'm specifically interested in "discussions of the word," as you put it, TedWrigley, and other uses, like verbatim reports of what was said or written.
I had hoped that the third and fourth paragraphs of my question made it clear that I understand why using the n-word in any other sense has the effects you're describing.

Comment: @AmeetSharma: Because this just shouldn't be an issue anymore. And this is how we make so the full word used by people not reclaiming it for themselves, outs people as a racist. It's not complicated. It IS, time to get over it.

Comment: @TedWrigley: "There is literally **no** conversation that **requires**..."
I don't know about "requires," but your comment is actually a good case in point: as an ESL speaker, it took me a minute to understand what you mean by the c-word, and I'm blissfully unaware of the k-word.  Spelling these words out **would** have eased communication.

Comment: @AHoodedStranger: The k-word is an ethnic slur for Jews; you can find it quickly enough with a web search. But speaking honestly, ***not*** knowing that word will not hurt you in any way. It only serves to identify antisemites who are already open about their antisemitism. Like a fart, we can smell the stink of it without making a fine point of it in language.

Comment: @CriglCragl, "Because this just shouldn't be an issue anymore. And this is how we make so the full word used by people not reclaiming it for themselves, outs people as a racist. " I don't understand. Are you saying that anyone non-black using the full word should be outed as racist regardless of context?

Comment: @AmeetSharma: No, he's saying that anyone who uses such a word incautiously — without careful, considerate framing and context — is taking a risk, and may have to accept consequences for that risk. I mean, if I use the c-word in the presence of my girlfriend (even if I'm doing it for the best and brightest of reasons), I have no one to blame but myself if I'm suddenly single. If one wants to use a highly charged word like the n-word in public, there are potential consequences one must avert or be prepared for. Gamblers shouldn't be whiners...

Comment: @JustSomeOldMan - Given the existence of a reliable euphemism, what do you lose in the meta-conversation other than the (racially aggressive) impactive force of the actual word? Or, if you think that's important to preserve, then why?

Answer (score 1):

*Brief Summary of this answer:* The word, like any taboo word, is (effectively) off-limits *because* a decisive enough portion of today's society has declared it off-limits. Whether or not you think they are right to do so doesn't change the fact that this has happened. When you use it, whether or not your intention is to express "I am a racist," that's how it will be perceived.

---

**Language is a form of communication that draws its meaning from context.** Every era and culture has taboo words that cannot readily be spoken for one reason or another --this list changes and alters over time due to cultural drift. In the ancient Jewish tradition, the name of God must never be written fully out or spoken --it is too sacred. As recently as a generation ago, certain terms referring frankly to sexual acts were never reproduced in print by any reputable publication.

In contemporary America, there is an increasingly widespread understanding that the only current usage of the "n" word, when spoken or spelled out in full with an "-er" ending (as having diverged decisively from the in-group variant with the "-a" ending), is to offend and injure, through **symbolic endorsement of a white supremacist world view**. According to that understanding, those who do not wish to deliberately offend will self-censor, regardless of other context. As this view becomes more dominant, that becomes the *effective* meaning of the term in all public discourse whether or not that matches the actual intentions of the speaker or writer.

**The fact that academic and journalistic usages of the word were previously considered acceptable is largely irrelevant.** Anyone, *in the year 2021*, who writes the "n" word out in full is well advised to know what they will be perceived as expressing and why.

*Citations:*

1. [How the N-Word Became Unsayable](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/04/30/opinion/john-mcwhorter-n-word-unsayable.html) - *NY Times*
2. [Should You Say the N Word?](https://www.washingtonpost.com/opinions/2021/05/07/should-you-say-n-word-no-especially-if-youre-not-black/) - *Washington Post*

Comment: “There is a general common understanding that the only usage of the "n" word, when spelled out in full with an "-er" ending, is to offend and injure, through symbolic endorsement of a white supremacist world view” – nonpartisan citation greatly needed. Bolinger explicitly spells out the words in a serious philosophical context. And then there’s Mark Twain and Harper Lee right off the bat.

Comment: What citations would qualify as "non-partisan" in your view?

Comment: Also, you omitted my clause "In contemporary America." The bulk of my answer is explaining that the usage of the word is different now because of the common usage of these particular times.

Comment: "is to offend and injure, through symbolic endorsement of a white supremacist world view"... In this incident: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9_-gn8Mm2xc did this white fan deliberately seek to offend by reciting the song lyrics?

Comment: @JustSomeOldMan - Citations added as requested. Since you never answered my question of what you would consider as "nonpartisan" I'll just have to assume you'll find these acceptable.

Comment: @AmeetSharma - You're talking about the divergent variant, as described in my post above, as well as in McWhorter. That's a related, but separate discussion that I don't intend to tackle --except to question why is it so important to people that they be allowed to say this particular word? Where's the positive value in it?

Comment: You have changed the original quote several times now. And I see why you inquired about “non-partisan”. No, opinion columnists from the NYT and WP are most certainly not nonpartisan, as their bias ratings from allsides, adfontes, and MBFC as well as their reputations indicate. I feel you already knew this though. Finally, you are referring to literal pundits who presume to be moral authorities. This is not a serious answer.

Comment: @JustSomeOldMan - I edited to improve the answer in light of your and others' comments --something I do for any answer I provide. But the part you ignored was in there from the start (view the edit history). If you have additional *constructive* criticism, I'll respond to it as well. // Since my answer refers to the existence of a widespread *opinion*, opinion columnists are appropriate citations. // Why are you so passionate in defense of this word? What's your agenda? Mine is to try to answer the original question as given.